# Problems with PDF, Adobe acrobat reader or Foxit reader?

Tags: firefox, pdf, acrobat, apache-fop, foxit-reader

I generate PDF 1.4 with Apache FOP. It works well with all browsers and PDF viewers. There is only one exception, when I open it from Firefox with Foxit Reader (6.1.1.1031) and save it AND once again open it with Adobe Acrobat Reader (9.3 and higher) it raises an error and do not show a lot of data in Adobe Acrobat reader. Does anybody had similar problems? Do I need to check my PDF template or is it a Foxit problem?

Comment: Please provide a sample file both before and after saving in FF/Foxit.

Comment: Sorry, I can't there is a lot of confidential information in that document, but I am working on testing data and will provide PDF as soon as possible. One more remark, when I open the same socument with Foxit reader, everything is fine, and after I save it, Adobe Acrobat opens PDF correctly. I am suspecting, that it is Foxit's plugins fault.